# ssh connection to host port 22 connection refused

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

I use a VMware virtualization system. I have centos release 7 as my operating system. I installed hadoop2.7.1. After installing Hadoop I ran the command :`#hdfs namenode -format`, it ran successfully. But when I run the command :`#./start-all.sh` it gives me errors. I tried several proposals that I saw on the internet but the problem persists

```
[root@MASTER sbin]# ./start-all.sh
    This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh
    21/06/17 19:06:27 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
    Starting namenodes on [MASTER]
    root@master's password:
    MASTER: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-root-namenode-MASTER.out
    localhost: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
    Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
    0.0.0.0: ssh: connect to host 0.0.0.0 port 22: Connection refused
    21/06/17 19:06:49 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
    starting yarn daemons
    starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-root-resourcemanager-MASTER.out
    localhost: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide ssh-key less access to all your worker nodes in hosts file, even localhost. Read instruction in the [Tutorial of How To Set Up SSH Keys on CentOS 7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys-on-centos7).

At last test access without password by `ssh localhost` and `ssh [yourworkernode]`.

Also, run `start-dfs.sh` and if was successful run `start-yarn.sh`.

Comment: Thanks Majid Hajibaba, I have a problem with the command # hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/Justin.
[hdfs@MASTER ~]$ hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/Justin
21/06/20 11:04:04 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
mkdir: `/user/Justin': No such file or directory

Comment: You must first cerate `user` directory in HDFS and then create `Justin` directory inside it. So you need do ` hdfs dfs -mkdir /user` and then ` hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/Justin`

Comment: When I execute command to create user 
[hdfs@MASTER ~]$ hdfs dfs -mkdir /user
 21/06/20 13:51:54 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
mkdir: Cannot create directory /user. Name node is in safe mode.

Comment: Check your workers' disk! it may be a disk full in one of the workers. If not, or yes (after increase disk), leave safe mode by `hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave`