# hadoop Starting namenodes on [ubuntu] ubuntu: Permission denied (publickey,password)

Tags: hadoop, ubuntu-16.04

Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Hadoop 3.3.1

when I run start-dfs.sh,

> hadoop@ubuntu:~/hadoop/sbin$ start-dfs.sh 
> Starting namenodes on [ubuntu]
> ubuntu: Warning: Permanently added 'ubuntu' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
> ubuntu: Permission denied (publickey,password).
> Starting datanodes
> localhost: Warning: Permanently added 'localhost' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
> localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password).
> Starting secondary namenodes [ubuntu]
> ubuntu: Permission denied (publickey,password).
> 2021-06-25 18:05:42,961 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... >using builtin-java classes where applicable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ubuntu: ssh: connect to host ubuntu port 22: Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68129061/ubuntu-ssh-connect-to-host-ubuntu-port-22-connection-refused)

Comment: Read this page, carefully - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HADOOP2/ConnectionRefused + [Your network, your problem](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HADOOP2/YourNetworkYourProblem). 1) Make sure you have a passwordless SSH key. 2) Do `ssh` between the local and hostname endpoints in addition to telnet

Comment: Provide key less access to workers. Read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68053356/2527458

Comment: @MajidHajibaba,using 'ssh-copy-id username@remote_host' ,it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem.
I resolved using the following shell commands.

```sh
ssh-keygen -t rsa 

cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys 

chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```